# Bootstrap3 - Getting navbar elements to take up entire width

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to create a webpage using bootstrap3 but have run into a problem in the navigation bar. I want the navigation links (there are 4 - "Web Design" "Development" "Photography" "Blog") to equally divide the space available in the horizontal navbar. At the min they are just piling up on the left. Here is a segment of the code - hopefully I haven't missed out an important bit. I have NOT amended the bootstrap CSS at all.

```
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Navbar -->
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="active col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#">Development</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#">Photography</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#">Blog</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: why is your navigation inside your page content? why do you have a row without columns?

Comment: Ok that was retarded of me...the nav shouldn't have been inside the page content and the columns thing was that I had forgotten to put the class bits back after experimenting with something else. But the problem is still the same

Comment: Not sure there is a navigation option in bootstrap to fill out the menu, but you could use the row/column part to make your own.. but then you'll loose adaptiveness of the normal menu. Alternatively you could force the nav items to have centered text and force them wider, so they fill out a bit more.

Comment: I tried forcing using width:25% (I take it that's the kinda thing you mean?) but that then screwed up the menu on mobile devices since it retains the styling. Looks good on larger screens though. What do you mean using the row/column part? I can't get it to register any kind of formatting from using row classes and then using columns on the li bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forced a few changes in the bootstrap layout with a couple of css rules, see if this doesn't float your boat :)

http://jsbin.com/xeniwonujeti/1/

my css changes:

```
.nav { width: 100%;}
.nav li { width: 25%; text-align: center; }
```

Obviously this will limit dynamic menu changes and you'll have to change it if the amount of links changes.

Comment: My problem with this is that it carries over to the mobile menu as well

Comment: Then we add a media query to only apply it on devices above 768px. updated the jsbin :)

Comment: Awesome. Bit of a newbie and had literally just decided that media queries might be what I have to do. You're a legend thank you :)

Comment: Since the width is hard-coded to `25%`, this won't work if there are more or less than 4 nav items.